# Cannot open C, C++ and Objective-C compiler(clang) on Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, compiling, gcc, c++, clang

I was on the Ubuntu Software Center and downloaded "C, C++ and Objective-C compiler(clang)." I didn't see it anywhere so i went to "search your computer and online resources" and didn't see it anywhere. I went to Ubuntu Software Center and went to the "installed" tab and searched for it. But it was not there (by the way it said that it was installed when I searched for it again except this as in the all software center in Ubuntu software center). This was weird and annoying so I went to terminal and entered `open  C, C++ and Objective-C compiler` but it said that it couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console. All helpful answers will be fully appreciated.

BTW my question is not a duplicate of "How can I know what programs some apt-get package contains?" as suggested by muru as one question is asking about how can they know what a package contains where my question is asking about where my download even is, **obvious difference**

Comment: How exactly did you run the programs from terminal, and what exactly was the output on the terminal? Did you try `gcc`, `c++`, `clang`. If I try those I get fatal error because I did not provide them a file to compile. If they are not installed Ubuntu reports that they are not installed and suggests how to install them.

Comment: `clang` is the package name. Now use the other question see what files it provides.

Comment: If not a dupe, can you [edit] to explain (a) your goal, and (b) what you know so far? Do you already know how to use Clang, such that you've tried the `clang` and `clang++` commands but they're missing? If so, please let us know, and also type `clang` in a terminal without pressing Enter and press Tab twice (that'll show you what commands you have that start with `clang`, if any). ***Or*** if you don't know [how to use Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html), then this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and you should tell us about what you want to do/learn.

Comment: your problem is that clang is not a "program" or something with a GUI you run or open. It is a compiler you use in the console `clang file.c` or from some IDEs to compile stuff

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new to Linux. In Linux world things are different than Windows. On Windows you may double click a program to run it. But in Linux most of the programs are run from the terminal. Windows also have programs like this too.

For example, in Windows you may have a program in your current directory named gcc.exe and you can run it from cmd by typing `gcc.exe`. It's same in Linux too. You can run a program by typing just the program's name in the terminal.

For example you can run gcc in Linux by typing `gcc` in a terminal and hit Enter. It will throw you a error if you type `open gcc` because open is a command used for another purpose, not running programs.

And the "C, C++ and Objective-C compiler" line you saw in the Software Center was the **DESCRIPTION** of the package, not the programs name. "C, C++ and Objective-C compiler" actually installed the package clang and its dependencies.

You can run clang by typing `clang` in a terminal.

But first, I recommend you to browse articles about the differences between Windows and Linux before using Linux. If you don't you will be clueless about what's happening in your machine and you might break it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't see clang anywhere in the Software Center because you haven't successfully installed it. Make sure that clang is installed by installing it from the terminal. If clang is already installed, nothing else will happen except a message will say that clang is already installed. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 this command installs the default version of clang (clang-3.8). Clang 4.0 is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 17.04 and later. Try [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931474/cannot-open-clang-after-i-downloaded-it/931497#931497) of compiling and running a hello world program in Ubuntu with clang.

After you have installed clang and run an example program, you may be interested in knowing where the clang executable is installed. For this run the command `which clang`. The results of `which clang` are:

```
/usr/bin/clang
```