# How do I run clang after installing it?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, c, clang

I have downloaded clang. When I got onto terminal and type `clang` it results in the error `no input files`.

Comment: You need to pass an input file to it. e.g. `clang your_file.c`

Comment: You need to know that clang is only a compiler, which make an executable file. Maybe you are looking for an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), which you are used too from Windows. Look for IDE for linux.

Comment: as people said clang is only a compiler -> it runs only in console. No GUI .. I would recommend e.g. [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) as a good tool where you can choose between gcc, clang and others

Comment: Do you have a source code file that you are trying to compile? (As `clang` says, you have not given it any input files.) What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The `clang: error: no input files` error in your question means exactly what it says. You need to specify an input file after typing `clang` in the terminal in order to tell clang what code to run.

This example uses the clang package from the default Ubuntu repositories (clang-3.8) and the following source code for hello.c.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    printf("hello world\n"); 
}
```

Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing hello.c (the input file) and compile it using the following command:

```
clang hello.c
```

The compiled executable file will be named a.out. Run it using the following command:

```
./a.out
```

The results of `./a.out` are:

```
hello world
```